# Conditional HTML in Codebehind vs Inline

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having trouble finding documentation on this subject, perhaps because I don't know the proper way to explain it. Please take a look at the following simplified code:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            <% if (Page.IsPostBack == true) { %>
            alert("PAGE IS POSTBACK");
            <% } else { %>
            alert("PAGE IS NOT A POSTBACK");
            <%} %>

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**This works perfectly,** but I would like to put this code on my codebehind page so I make database calls and change the jquery based on what my methods return. Is there a codebehind alternative to the inline code as I have shown above?

Comment: technology used? MVC? ASP?

Comment: have you looked into Literals?

Comment: @Johan, Webforms on ASP.Net.

Comment: @Mike, I will have to see if they can be used as scripts or not. Thanks.

Comment: @Zerkey this may be an overkill of a post/answer but take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572735/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-dynamic-html-insertion-issue-telerik.  You certainly can add dynamic HTML and scripts, you'll just need to trigger any appropriate functions from preexisting or new scripts after the load has completed (with the appropriate updated identifiers of course).

Comment: @MikeHometchko I read most of it, and that is very similar to a problem I had last week. Partial postbacks (updatepanel) cause issues with jQuery and your .click events will not fire on new/changed dom elements.

Comment: @Zerkey yea I eventually figured that out and answered the question below, wasn't too sure if that would be any help but it sounds like it may be close enough to at least push you on the right path.  At any rate, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call get a value of code behind from aspx page, you can create a public property and access it using `<%= xxxx %>` -

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ("<%= PageIsPostBack  %>" == "True") {
            alert("PAGE IS POSTBACK");
        } else {
            alert("PAGE IS NOT A POSTBACK");
        }
    });
</script>

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool PageIsPostBack
    {
        get { return Page.IsPostBack; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Note: for `Page.IsPostBack`, you can even access from aspx like this without public property -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (<%= Page.IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower() %>") {
            alert("PAGE IS POSTBACK");
        } else {
            alert("PAGE IS NOT A POSTBACK");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have used the first example in previous works. The reason I am so partial to my current code is because if the (if) fails the included code will not even be sent in the response to the user, which I thought was useful. I think my inline code may be the most practical for this situation. Despite this, thank you for your thoughtful answer and provided code!